# WPF Dependency Property ObservableCollection showing multiple values

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a user control in WPF which I want to pass a list of items to when I use the user control in another window (the user control contains a ComboBox and label and has some important functionality). This works fine if I have a single control on my page, but if I have two I get the values listed from both my user controls, presumably because the DependencyProperty is static. I can't remove the static as it throws an error when registering the dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxValuesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxValues", typeof(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue>), typeof(SystemConfigComboBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue>()));

public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue> ComboBoxValues
{
    get { return GetValue(ComboBoxValuesProperty) as ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue>; }
    set { SetValue(ComboBoxValuesProperty, value); }
}
```

Below shows both user controls ComboBoxes containing Value1 and Value2

```
<customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox SystemConfigEntry="Entry1" ComboBoxLabel="Combo 1" ComboBoxWidth="300">
    <customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox.ComboBoxValues>
        <customEditors:ComboBoxValue DisplayValue="Value1" ActualValue="VALUE1" />
    </customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox.ComboBoxValues>
</customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox>
<customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox SystemConfigEntry="Entry2" ComboBoxLabel="Combo 2" ComboBoxWidth="300">
    <customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox.ComboBoxValues>
        <customEditors:ComboBoxValue DisplayValue="Value2" ActualValue="VALUE2" />
    </customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox.ComboBoxValues>
</customEditors:SystemConfigComboBox>
```

and just for information the ComboBoxValue class:-

```
public class ComboBoxValue : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayValue", typeof(string), typeof(ComboBoxValue));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActualValue", typeof(string), typeof(ComboBoxValue));

    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public string ActualValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ActualValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActualValueProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the `ObservableCollection` in the constructor of the control class and not in the `DependencyProperty.Register` method:

```
public class SystemConfigComboBox
{
    public SystemConfigComboBox()
    {
        ComboBoxValues = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue>();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxValues", typeof(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxValue>), typeof(SystemConfigComboBox)));

    ...
}
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563(v=vs.110).aspx